# Rails select_tag alphabetical order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have this `select_tag`

```
select_tag :id, options_for_select(Portal.all.collect{|p| [p.name, portal_datum_path(p.id)]}, [@portal.name, portal_datum_path(@portal)]), :onChange => "window.location=($(this).val());"
```

It allows a user to select a portal on which to see certain elements i want to display these portals in alphabetical order.

I tried ordering the :name in the controller but no win.

```
def index
  @portals = Portal.with_name_or_subdomain(params[:keyword]).order(:name).limit(100)
end
```

I looked at the rails docs there are no built in options within the select_tag itself is there some secret option that i should be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after a hour all you have to do is `.sort` the array of options that are passed into the options_for_select. this is my hack its a fix but not very sexy

```
select_tag :id, options_for_select(Portal.all.collect{|p| [p.name, portal_datum_path(p.id)]}.sort, [@portal.name, portal_datum_path(@portal)]), :onChange => "window.location=($(this).val());"
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

alter it to

```
select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(portals,:name, :id, 1), :onChange => "window.location=($(this).val());"**strong text**
```

Answer (score 1):

Collect your options into an array, as you have done:

```
options = Portal.all.collect{|p| [p.name, portal_datum_path(p.id)]},    [@portal.name, portal_datum_path(@portal)])
```

Then sort:

```
options.sort!{ |x, y| x[0] <=> y[0] }
```

I do this in a monkey patch of options_for_select, which is part of a module I built to handle all sorts of select stuff, since sorting a select like this is more common than not.

```
def options_for_select(options, selected_items:nil, alphabetize: true)
  options.sort!{ |x, y| x[0] <=> y[0] } if alphabetize 
  super(options, selected_items)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select_tag :id, options_for_select(Portal.all.order(name: :asc).collect{|p| [p.name, portal_datum_path(p.id)]}.sort, [@portal.name, portal_datum_path(@portal)]), :onChange => "window.location=($(this).val());"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).